# What language is used in Google Desktop gadgets?

Tags: javascript, google-desktop

The language Google Desktop gadgets use resembles JavaScript, but it's different in subtle ways. For example, I saw this line in a gadget:

```
options(HISTORY_OPTIONS_NAME) = items_.join("|");
```

which looks like it's assigning to a function call. That's just not OK in JavaScript... what language is this? And what exactly is that line doing?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the gadgets use JavaScript. Where did you get this line from? Are you sure it's not

```
options[HISTORY_OPTIONS_NAME] = items_.join("|");
```

(note brackets)

Comment: A quick googling reveals that he probably saw it here[1], but that does indeed confirm that it is Javascript.


   [1]: http://code.google.com/p/google-wikipedia/source/browse/trunk/wikipedia_history.js?spec=svn3&r=3#77

Comment: That file does indeed have the mysterious line in it though, and it's definitely illegal in JavaScript. Is that file just broken?

Comment: @Daniel: yea thats just the code i looked at. i think it works.. i put an alert in after that line, and it gets called and nothing complains.